# pictures keep changing on the form, there should be at least 5 pictures on every different groupbox using loop

Tags: vb.net

I want a way of loading 5 pictures on every refresh. i have over 300 pictures in the database and i want them to load every 5 picture on form load. and then they sray there for 10sec and then the next 5 loads n keeps loading till al the pictures are loaded then it restarts again from the start.
it should be using a loop. because i have a dynamic way of loading my pictures and textboxes. so how could i jst load 5 pictured and then the next 5 after the first 5 have disappeared. all should happen on one form. maybe even use ashock.. or any other way.

Comment: From your description, there is probably no Loop involved, just timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`or any other way.`

you can do like this, First get all those 300 pictures in the `load event` and store that in a [**datatable**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) (using `datatable` will shrinks the possibility to connect to back end multiple times).Then use a [**timer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) in your form and set its [**interval**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) for 5000 ms(i.e 5 seconds). use a `global variable` to to track how many pictures are shown, increment it by 5 for every [**tick event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)'s call(`Tick event` will get fired when interval assigned by you gets elapsed. - ex: for every 5 seconds). now inside the `tick event`, get five pictures from the datatable(use that `global variable` to get the next 5 images). Display those five images by replacing the old ones.and once that `global variable` reaches 300 again reset it to 0. This cycle will ends only if you [**stop**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.timers.timer.stop.aspx) the timer.

Hope this will give you an idea to accompolish your task.

Comment: thank you so much.. mr. rajaprabhu..i wil try it and let u know if it workd. thanks